# Error when trying to use NODE_DELETE to update Relay Store. Uncaught Error: RelayMutationQuery: Expected field `stores` on `viewer` to be a connection

Tags: relayjs

I am trying to delete a store from a stores connection. I keep getting the error:

Uncaught Error: RelayMutationQuery: Expected field `stores` on `viewer` to be a connection.

My viewer object is something like this:

```
{
  "__dataID__":"VXNlcjp2aWV3ZXJfZml4ZWQ=",
  "id":"VXNlcjp2aWV3ZXJfZml4ZWQ=",
  "stores":{
    "__dataID__":"client:-1121235371",
    "edges":[
      {
       "__dataID__":"client:-1121235372",
       "node":{
          "__dataID__":"U3RvcmU6NTg0MmIwODE1ZDY0NTY1NWU4NTVhOTc1",
          "id":"U3RvcmU6NTg0MmIwODE1ZDY0NTY1NWU4NTVhOTc1",
          "_id":"5842b0815d645655e855a976",
          "address":null,
          "closingHours":null,
          "contactNumber":null,
          "name":"s5",
          "openingHours":null,
          "isActive":true
       }
    },
    {
       "__dataID__":"client:-1121235373",
       "node":{
          "__dataID__":"U3RvcmU6NThhYmM2ZjcyNTgyNjI5NDVhYzZkMGEx",
          "id":"U3RvcmU6NThhYmM2ZjcyNTgyNjI5NDVhYzZkMGEx",
          "_id":"58abc6f7258262945ac6d0a2",
          "address":null,
          "closingHours":null,
          "contactNumber":null,
          "name":"Dete",
          "openingHours":null,
          "isActive":true
       }
    }
   ]
  }
}
```

And my mutation file is:

```
import Relay from 'react-relay';

export default class DeleteStoreMutation extends Relay.Mutation {
  getMutation() {
    return Relay.QL`mutation{ DeleteStoreMutation }`;
  }

  getFatQuery() {
    return Relay.QL`
      fragment on DeleteStoreMutationPayload {
        viewer
        deletedId
      }
   `;
  }

  getConfigs() {
    console.log(this.props.viewer);
    return [{
      type: 'NODE_DELETE',
      parentName: 'viewer',
      parentID: this.props.viewer.id,
      connectionName: 'stores',
      deletedIDFieldName: 'deletedId'
    }];
  }

  getVariables() {
    return {
      _id: this.props.storeId,
    };
  }
}
```

GraphQL Schema index.js

```
import { UserType } from './types'
import { GraphQLObjectType, GraphQLSchema } from 'graphql'
import { nodeField, nodeInterface } from './node'
import modules from './modules'
import { AuthService } from '../services'

let RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'RootQuery',
  fields: {
    viewer: {
      type: UserType,
      resolve: async ({ viewerId }) => AuthService.getViewer(viewerId)
    },
    node: nodeField
  }
});


let RootMutation = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "RootMutation",
  fields: () => ({ ...modules.mutations  })
 });

let schema = new GraphQLSchema({
  query: RootQuery,
  mutation: RootMutation
});
```

export default schema;

UserType.js snippet

```
const UserType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'User',
  description: 'A user',
  fields: () => ({
    id: globalIdField(),
    _id: {
      type: GraphQLID
    },
    stores: {
      type: StoreConnection,
      resolve: (user) => StoreService.getStores(user)
    },
  }),

  interfaces: [nodeInterface]
});
```

store-connection-type.js

```
import { GraphQLObjectType, GraphQLList, GraphQLNonNull } from 'graphql';
import PageInfo from './page-info-type'
import Cursor from './cursor-type'
import StoreType from './store-type' 

const StoreEdge = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'StoreEdge',
  fields: () => ({
    cursor: {
      type: Cursor,
      resolve: (store) => ({ value: store._id.toString() })
    },
    node: {
      type: StoreType,
      resolve: (store) => store
    },
  }),
});

const StoreConnection = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'StoreConnection',
  fields: () => ({
    edges: {
      type: new GraphQLList(StoreEdge),
      resolve: (stores) => stores
    },
    pageInfo: {
      type: PageInfo,
      resolve: () => ({hasNextPage: false, hasPreviousPage: false})
    },
  }),
});

export default StoreConnection;
```

[image: GraphiQL Screenshot]

Comment: Can you provide the definition of your Viewer type from your GraphQL schema? I suspect that "stores" is a list, not a connection.

Comment: @NevillS I have updated the question with more information. Any help would be great. Thanks a ton.

Comment: OK so it *does* look like your `stores` field is a valid GraphQL connection. However, the Relay mutation query logic doesn't agree, so it must be acting on some incomplete information.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the (likely) issue here is that the mutation query building logic is getting confused by incomplete information. I suspect that it's just having a hard time with your fat query - in theory the data should be accessible in the local graph, but I'm not 100% sure at what stage these types of defensive validations run.

I'd recommend updating your fat query to be more specific:

```
Relay.QL`
      fragment on DeleteStoreMutationPayload {
        viewer {
          stores
        }
        deletedId
      }
`
```

I'm about 50% sure that's what that mutation config expects to see when you give it both a `parentName` and a `connectionName`.

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure that's it. The error message could be a bit more helpful here (I think the issue is more that "stores" isn't in the fat query, not that "stores" isn't a connection). But having super-specific error messages isn't always that easy to do!

Comment: I tried what you are suggesting, unfortunately the error is still the same :(

Comment: OK, maybe the server-side mutation type is wonky. Can you add that to the question as well?

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across the fix. The StoreConnection wasn't taking any args, in this case connectionArgs, because of which relay wasn't recognising it as a connection.

Fixed it by adding connectionArgs to Stores field.